# Hybris: Difference between Content Page,Category Page & Product Page

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Can we use category page or product page for any other pages in hybris ?
In which scenario we go for content page, category page , product page ?
What will happen if i use product page as my home page or is that possible of doing it in hybris ?
As far i know is that the template structure is different for three pages. is there any other difference ?

Answer (score 3):

I think there are three main points for the difference between those pages.

1. Yes, the template that is bind to a page type and so the structure
   that you have.
2. The pages have different attributes on them. For example the categoryPageType has the attribute 'category'. So you have the possibility to maintain those attribute. For example the CategoryPageController will look for this attribute if you open a CategoryPage.
3. By having different page types you have the possibility to do a clean structure in your backend. So you can search for 'categoryPage' or 'contentPage' and so on.

So now to your question. Yes you could use every page type for every stuff you want. But it is like you use a category for representing a product for example... It is just use the right thing for the right requirements.